# Continuously changing the color of an object on canvas

Tags: inkscape

To continuously change the color of an object, you may use the *Fill and Stroke* dialog and drag in its bands or color wheel.

Is it possible to do it *directly on the canvas, without any dialog?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, albeit only in the HSL color model:

1. Select an object.
2. Drag an (invisible) line (a ray, radius) from the actual fill or stroke color into canvas.
3. Then – still with left mouse button pressed – change the *angle* of this invisible line.
4. Finally, if you are satisfied with the new color, release the mouse button:

[image]

This method will change the **hue** of the object(s). To change

- **saturation** (the pureness of the color), press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key,
- **lightness**, press and hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.
- **alpha channel** (transparency), press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

You may release and press these modifier keys repeatedly during this procedure to switch among these 4 modes (hue, saturation, lightness, alpha).

Comment: Oh my, that's fun!  You learn something new every day!!!