# Continuously changing the stroke width

Tags: inkscape, stroke

To change the stroke width of an object, you may use, e.g., the *Stroke style* tab of the *Fill and Stroke* dialog, or the context menu of the *Stroke width* in the selected style indicator:

[image]

But the change of the stroke width is *not continuous.*

Is it possible to continuously changing the stroke width by dragging with mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

1. Select an object (or more objects).
2. Drag an (invisible) line (a ray, radius) from the *actual stroke width indicator* into canvas.

   [image]
3. Then – still with left mouse button pressed – change the *angle* of this invisible line.
4. Finally, when you are satisfied with the new stroke width, release the mouse button:

[image]

*Note:*
This method is very similar to the method for changing a *color* in [my other answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/157282/159652).